# How to use React in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I want to try Server Side Render in React, but my code doesn't work.

I should be missing something. But I don't know what it is as I'm new to react.

[image: SyntaxError]

Here's the code as well:

server/app.js

```js
import express from 'express';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import Home from '../src/index.js';

const app = express();
const content = renderToString(<Home />);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send(
   `
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>ssr</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${content}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
   `
   );
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listen:3001')
})
```

src/index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Hello World</div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Home
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server/app.js"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```js
{
    "presets": [
      "env"
    ],
    "plugins": []
}
```

Comment: Upgrade to Babel 7 and add the React preset, then try again.

Comment: To use react-jsx syntax, you need a transpiler.

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](https://alligator.io/react/server-side-rendering/) that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can not render react page from nodejs like ejs because react is not like any template. it is a library.But if you actually want it, then you need server side rendering. (SSR)

Answer (score 0):

```
const content = renderToString(<Home />);
```

you are using jsx here but not transpiling jsx into js. you need to install

```
npm i @babel/preset-react
```

also instead of "babel-preset-env" use this

```
npm i @babel/preset-env
```

then

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", ""@babel/preset-env]
}
```